# How to avoid mistakes index out of range?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, collections, deselect

I try to **select multiple items** in **collectionCell**, but if i tap **many times** for **deselect cell** i get an **error** `Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range`

On this line `selectedTimeIntervalArray.remove(at: indexPath.item)` on `indexPath.item == 1`.

How to avoid this **error**?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let selectedCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)

    if indexPath.item == 0 {
        selectedBackgroundColor(cell: selectedCell!)
        selectedTime = timeIntervalArray[indexPath.item]
        selectedTimeLabel.text = "Время - \(selectedTime)"
        selectedTimeIntervalArray.append(selectedTime)
    } else if indexPath.item == 1 {
        selectedBackgroundColor(cell: selectedCell!)
        selectedTime2 = timeIntervalArray[indexPath.item]
        selectedTimeIntervalArray.append(selectedTime2)
    }

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let deselectedCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)

    if indexPath.item == 0 {
        deselectedBackgroundColor(cell: deselectedCell!)
        selectedTime = ""
        selectedTimeIntervalArray.remove(at: indexPath.item)
    } else if indexPath.item == 1 {
        deselectedBackgroundColor(cell: deselectedCell!)
        selectedTime2 = ""
        selectedTimeIntervalArray.remove(at: indexPath.item)
    }

}
```

Comment: If you add two items into an array, and remove(at: 0), the array now only contains one item, so when you remove(at: 1) it'll crash. I suggest looking for a different way to store the selected state.

Comment: You don't want to do `selectedTimeIntervalArray.remove(at: indexPath.item)`. The index is not the correct one. The `indexPath.item` is not the index of the object in your array. Instead, `let index = timeIntervalArray.index(of:timeIntervalArray[indexPath.item]);  timeIntervalArray.remove(at: index)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you select the cell at `indexPath.item == 1`.
You do then

```
selectedTime2 = timeIntervalArray[indexPath.item]
selectedTimeIntervalArray.append(selectedTime2)
```

So we have: `selectedTimeIntervalArray == ["ValueOfSelectedTime2"]`

Now, we deselect the item.
You do then:

```
selectedTimeIntervalArray.remove(at: indexPath.item)
```

So you do in our case:

```
selectedTimeIntervalArray.remove(at: 1)
```

Index 1, really? No, that causes a crash. Because `selectedTimeIntervalArray` has only one item and it's at index 0.

`indexPath.item` is not the `index` of the object you stored in your array.

Instead, retrieve first the correct index:

```
let objectToRemove = timeIntervalArray[indexPath.item]‌
let index = selectedTimeIntervalArray.index(of: objectToRemove​)
```

Then remove it:

```
 selectedTimeIntervalArray.remove(at: index)
```

Comment: Thanks, i understand. It helped me.